# Extruding Problems

Tags: modeling

When I try to extrude a face, or several faces, the faces rearrange themselves with respect to my perspective, so that strange polygonal cavities are formed and I cannot achieve the desired effect.  I think I probably toggled something by accident; can anyone point me in the right direction?

[image: inverted face]

Comment: You have *face snapping* enabled, perhaps  that is causing some confusing behavior. I'm not quite sure I understand what you mean by "faces rearrange themselves with respect to my perspective".. Is it possible you could upload a short gif or something showing what happens? (not sure what is what in the screenshot)

Comment: The issue was I had the Magnet icon toggled, that was altering my extrusions.  Thank you so much for pointing me in the right direction!